# javascript, fix all image src after change domain

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

i changed the domain of my site from domain1.com to domain2.com

all images at my site are like this:

```
<img src="http://domain1.com/uploads/4353.jpg" />
<img src="http://domain1.com/uploads/54334.jpg" />
<img src="http://domain1.com/uploads/5345.jpg" />
```

I want to change them to:

```
<img src="http://domain2.com/uploads/4353.jpg" />
<img src="http://domain2.com/uploads/54334.jpg" />
<img src="http://domain2.com/uploads/5345.jpg" />
```

I get the src of all by jQuery like this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
     var oldsrc = $(this).attr('src');

});
```

how to replace it with new src

Comment: Sounds like you need to modify your HTML source rather than applying a JS transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('img').prop('src', function () { return this.src.replace('domain1','domain2'); })
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2sX7c/)**

Comment: Shouldn't you use the jquery attr() function instead of prop()?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('img').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('domain1','domain2'));
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kQS68/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('img').each(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('domain1.com', 'domain2.com');
  $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src').replace("http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com"));
});
```